# Apple Store Connect: Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles grayed out

Tags: developer-program

I want to add one of my friends to our development team in App Store Connect, so he can see/add Certificates and Provisioning Profiles. There is a Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles checkbox under Developer Resources, but it is greyed out.

How do I add my teammate with this permission?

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to assign the user the Developer role before you can give access to Developer Resources. You do that by checking the "Developer" checkbox in your screenshot.

Note that if you have enrolled as an Individual, as opposed to as an Organization, you’ll not be able to add additional developers - and this you cannot give others access to the Developer Resources.

Comment: It turns out you can't check ``Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles`` if you have an ``individual`` account. You must convert your account to ``organization`` to give that permission. Mention this and I accept your answer.