# Could not access apple developer resource (Certificates, IDs & Profiles)

Tags: app-store-connect, developer-program, enterprise

I joined a paid Apple Developer Enterprise Program last two years with **admin access**, recently I found I don't have the certificate & provisioning profiles page permissions anymore. The user access page had been moved from `developer.apple.com` to `appstoreconnect.apple.com` last year for enterprise program account. Here is my finding:

[image]

However, I **couldn't find the team entry in the team list** in site https://developer.apple.com/account, are there any other ways to check out the certificate list?

I checked the [help page](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/) and no luck, any helps?

**UPDATE**

After inspecting the network requests for appstoreconnect and developer.apple.com about the team list.

- AppStoreConnect: `https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/olympus/v1/session`
- AppleDeveloper: `https://developer.apple.com/services-account/QH65B2/account/getTeams`

My expected team object just didn't be shown in AppleDeveloper response, maybe this is a logic bug of Apple?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apple Store Connect: Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles grayed out](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/358552/apple-store-connect-access-to-certificates-identifiers-profiles-grayed-out)

Comment: No, I have the admin access already, check the screenshot above. @ankii

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not having permissions". According to your screenshots, you do have permissions - so you must mean something else. Do you get an error message when you open the certificates tab? - or is the tab not visible for you? or what happens exactly?

Comment: I could only review the team's `Users and Access` in [appstoreconnect](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/), but I couldn't find the team in [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/account) when switching teams. @jksoegaard

Comment: The certificates are not in App Store Connect, they're in Apple Developer. If you log on to Apple Developer, do you see the tab named "Certificates, IDs & Profiles" ? If not, click "Membership" and let us know what it says for "Your Roles"

Comment: I knew that and I had joined a few teams, the point is I couldn't find my expected team name when clicking my user name in the top-right corner to switch team. @jksoegaard

Comment: I thought the question was about the certificates - so you're saying you have no access at all to Apple Developer for this team? - The screenshot you have in your question, does that display that you're Admin for this particular team you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm my admin role access. Actually, it works in last year, but the team entry disappears recently, as I know. @jksoegaard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the final result status:

Apple just bans the Apple Enterprise Developer Program, that's why I can't see it in the list, it's under an unavailable state.

Anyway, if someone encountered something similar, contact the apple tech team directly.